# generating new variables in c

Tags: c, variables

Is is possible for your code to generate new variables in c? For example, if I made "example_variable = 15", is there any way to automatically generate 15 new variables such as: "generated_variable_1", "generated_variable_2", "generated_variable_3", all the way to "generated_variable_15"?

I'm very new to c, and I haven't had a proper introduction to it, so I only know the basics, especially when it comes to variables. I am pretty sure this is really high-level stuff, so I'm sorry if the question doesn't make sense. I am open to any suggestions for alternate ways of generating the variables.

I know there are probably answers already out there, but I've had trouble finding them and would like answers specific to what I'm looking for, as opposed to piecing together what I need from what I can find.

Comment: what's your goal with this?

Comment: The way to "generate" variables is usually called array: `int var[15]:` You can then acces these as `var[0]` to `var[14]` with the extra benefit that any integer expression can be inside the brackets.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Put shortly, I'm working with robotics (which is why I haven't been formally introduced to c) and I need my 'bot to run a series of actions, and then basically "record" the results of those actions by assigning them a variable, and then use the information it records to decide what to do next. The catch is, I don't know how much information it will need to store, so I want to be able to change the number quickly.

Comment: @JasonWalker then you need an array.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I’ve been looking into that. An array is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about - generating variables at runtime - is not possible in C. The reason is that C is a low-level language and does not expose an API for runtime manipulation. In fact, once compiled, C programs don't use variables - are values are stored directly in memory using memory addresses.

The closet equivalent to what you're looking for that's available in C is an "array". To declare an array, you can do:

```
int var[15];
int var2[n]; // in C99+, n is a variable saying how many elements you want in the array
```

You can also do this with `malloc`, but this is a bit more complicated and then you must free the values.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats exactly what I needed. I'm not familiar with C at all, so I don't know what it can and can't do yet. I should have thought about looking into arrays sooner, they'll make things MUCH easier for me. Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A running `C` program doesn't use your variable names at all. Those names were useful for the compiler to build the program, but are discarded before you run it. This means that in `C` (but not in interpreted languages like `python`):

- If you rename your variables, you get the *exact* same program
- If you do `strings <your program>` you won't see any variable names (unless you retained debugging symbols)

Hence, runtime is *too late* to create new variables. In `C`, variables are compile-time only. Of course, you can use arrays, or dictionaries, to *simulate* run-time variable creation, like the other answer, and a few commenters, suggest.

Comment: I see. I learnt python first, so I must not have picked up on the differences. Good to know, I never would've been able to figure that out on my own.